# How to pass an Integer constant

Tags: jsf, el

I have `<f:attribute name="someInt" value="#{1}"/>` which is retrieved from component in faces `Converter`. I found that expression `"#{1}"` evaluates to `Long` instead of `Integer` (was hoping there is something like `#{1}` for an `int` and `#{1L}` for a `long` but it doesn't work that way). It is possible to pass an `Integer` without emplyoing bean  e.g. `#{bean.castToInt(1)}`? Do I have to simply use `Long` for an integer numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `java.lang.Long.intValue()` method for this:

```
<f:attribute name="someInt" value="#{(1).intValue()}"/>
```